# margin centered button shifts to left in ipad

Tags: html, ios, css

It's my button:

```
<div id="body">
    <button>Hello</button>
</div>
```

and its style:

```
#body{
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#eee;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
button {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

It's centered, but let's see the result in ipad:

[image]

**It shifts to left.**

Take a look at this case: http://jsfiddle.net/c2HLe/9/

Note.
*This is similar to my previous question, but in this case I made it with a simple structure, so I think people can focus better on the problem.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center your button using `margin: 0 auto;`, you also need to define the width of the button. Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/c2HLe/10/).

Alternatively, you can also use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/c2HLe/18/).

```
#body{
    text-align: center;
}
 button {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

In your original CSS, if the width of the container (margin+border+padding+content width) exceeds 1024px (iPad viewport width), you will get unexpected results. So make sure you keep that in mind.